# iPad for lightweight vacation computing?

Tags: ipad

Vacation computing for me these days seems to have fairly few requirements that my phone alone can't easily support:

1. Offloading raw SLR photos from SD card to clear space and post online (often to facebook)
2. Offloading, editing down, and posting videos (facebook)

Is the iPad a suitable, flexible, enjoyable device for this sort of thing? If so, are there any apps or workflows that help?

Comment: Stop working, start enjoying. You can get back to your work when you get back. [/tongue-in-cheek]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of pro photographers who've started using the iPad for their first pass of editing. Vincent Laforet, who is highly respected wrote about his use of them at "[Using the iPad on set](http://blog.vincentlaforet.com/2010/06/17/using-the-ipad-on-set/)". Also "[12 Best iPad Photo Apps](http://www.tabletpcreview.com/default.asp?newsID=1614&review=12+Best+iPad+Photo+Apps)" has some suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that first link is the one you meant to post? It links to a page that doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: Did you even watch the video? Vince Laforet is one of the most respected photographers out there and he shows how he uses one of his iPads on a shoot for video, and stills.

Answer (score 0):

You can import photos using the iPad camera kit:
http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A